# How to check for nil and compare if != nil on Hashes?

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a key and value in a Hash is not nil (specifically the value), and if not nil, I want to compare the value of the Hash to a String object. If the value is not nil, it will also be a String.

Here's my code:

```
class Knight
  # read input, first line = N
  # adjacency list / hash, key = column
  # value should be content of each row
  # now we can index each matrix. easily
  # foreach matrix. (conditions) rel. to i
  # mark matrix. as visited and continue
  # break when matrix. = # | k
  @@n
  @@k
  @@adj_hash

  def _read
    @@n = gets.to_i
    @@adj_hash = Hash.new
    @@n.times do |x|
      temp = gets.strip.to_s
      if temp.include? "k"
        @@k = x
      end
      @@adj_hash[x] = temp.chars
    end
    @@adj_hash
  end

  def _jump(matrix, col, row, goal)
    found = false
    if matrix.dig(:col+1, :row+2) = goal
      col = col+1
      row = row+2
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col+2][row+1] = goal
      col = col+2
      row = row+1
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col+2][row-1] = goal
      col = col+2
      row = row-1
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col+1][row-2] = goal
      col = col+1
      row = row-2
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col-1][row-2] = goal
      col = col-1
      row = row-2
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col-2][row+1] = goal
      col = col-2
      row = row+1
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col-2][row-1] = goal
      col = col-2
      row = row-1
      found = true
    elsif matrix[col-1][row+2] = goal
      col = col-1
      row = row+2
      found = true
    end
    info = [found, col, row]
  end

  def find_path
    _read
    found = false
    col = 0
    row = 0
    steps = 0
    while !found
      curr = @@adj_hash[col][row]
      @@adj_hash[col][row] = '#'
      if _jump(curr, col, row, 'k')[0] = true
        steps += 1
        puts "Found 'k'"
        found = true
      elsif _jump(curr, col, row, '.')[0] = true
        col = _jump(curr, col, row, '.')[1]
        row = _jump(curr, col, row, '.')[2]
        steps += 1
        puts "Jumping..."
      end
      #if @@adj_hash[col][row] = 'k'
        found = true
      #end
    end
  end
end

knight = Knight.new
knight.find_path
```

If you see my method `_jump`,
the first if-condition is supposed to check for nil with the dig-method.
The other elsifs are how I compared Hash-value before I encounted nil-errors.

This is the error this code gives me:

> `knight.rb:29:in '_jump': undefined method '+' for :col:Symbol (NoMethodError)`

Comment: marty, your code appears to contain other errors (e.g., should `if matrix.dig(:col+1, :row+2) = goal` be `... == goal`?) and is very un-Ruby-like. Consider posting a separate question that asks how your code can be fixed and improved. If you do that you will need to clearly state the problem you are trying to solve (having something to do with a knight, presumably). If you can give a small example, all the better. When giving an example please always show the desired result (as a Ruby object).

Comment: For future reference, SO has a sister-site at Stack Exchange, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), which is a valuable resource for getting suggestions on improving *working code*.

Comment: @martyro : I don't see any check for `nil` in the code you posted. You can test for nil-ness of an `x` by using either `x.nil?` or `x == nil` or `x.equal?(nil)`, depending on your taste.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I felt physically ill entering some of the code in this program, but I tried to bruteforce my way to a solution for a leetcode-type problem. I agree I would prefer to get criticism on my Ruby code but I wanted to find a working solution first.

Comment: @user1934428 The nil-check was supposed to be the line ´matrix.dig(:col+1, :row+2)´ because my google searches all pointed to using the dig method somehow, but I couldn't get it to work. I used r4cc00n's solution for nil-checks and it worked as I hoped.

Comment: @martyro _"I wanted to find a working solution first"_ – nothing wrong with that approach, but you should reduce your code to that specific problem. Provide an example value for `matrix`, include the (not working) conditional and your expected result, i.e. maybe 9 lines of code (instead of 90).

Comment: @Stefan I will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @martyro : You don't pass a Hash to the parameter `matrix`. That's why `dig` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if an object/value is nil you can do it like this:

```rb
object.nil?
```

in your case (the value of a hash is something like): `your_hash[key].nil?`, with that said if you want to do something if the value is not nil you can do:

```rb
if !my_hash[my_key].nil?
end
```

or the ruby way:

```rb
unless my_hash[my_key].nil?
end
```

Also if you want to know whether a hash contains or not a key you can do it as follow:

```rb
your_hash.keys.include? key_to_search
```

If you want to compare 2 strings: `str1 == str2`, if you want to know if `str1` contains to `str2` as substring then `str1.include? str2`

Comment: Thx @Cary Swoveland nice catch as usual!